# apt-get -f install fails to correct dependencies

Tags: apt, software-installation, upgrade, dependencies

I recently tried a dist-upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04.  During the upgrade process, it reported problems with broken dependencies.  I noted the packages, hoping I could fix the problem later.

Now I seem to be stuck in a place where I can't to either install, fix or uninstall packages.

First, my repositories:

```
ralmond@Limu:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 
(20120425)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

# deb http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/ # disabled on upgrade to trusty disabled on upgrade to xenial
# deb https://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/linux/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src https://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/linux/ubuntu xenial main
# deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ # disabled on upgrade to bionic
```

I manually commented out the precise partner repo as that was possibly a problem.  All other older repos in sources.list and sources.list.d were commented out.

I try to run apt-get -f install to fix the broken dependencies, but I get

```
ralmond@Limu:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    debhelper : Depends: dh-autoreconf (>= 17~) but it is not installed
         Depends: dh-strip-nondeterminism (>= 0.028~) but 0.015-1 is installed
     libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.1-2ubuntu1) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu1 is installed
     libhtml-parser-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.26.0-4) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 is installed
                   Depends: perlapi-5.26.0
     libnet-ssleay-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.26.1-4build1) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 is installed
                  Depends: perlapi-5.26.1
     libxml-libxml-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.26.1-2ubuntu1) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 is installed
                  Depends: perlapi-5.26.1
     libxml-parser-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.26.0-4) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 is installed
                  Depends: perlapi-5.26.0
     systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 229-4ubuntu21.2) but 237-3ubuntu10 is installed
     texlive-binaries : Depends: libharfbuzz0b (>= 1.4.1) but 1.0.1-1ubuntu0.1 is installed
                Depends: libmpfr6 (>= 3.1.3) but it is not installed
                Depends: libpoppler73 (>= 0.62.0) but it is not installed
     texlive-extra-utils : Depends: libunicode-linebreak-perl but it is not installed
     texlive-generic-extra : Depends: texlive-plain-generic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installed
     texlive-generic-recommended : Depends: texlive-plain-generic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installed
     texlive-lang-chinese : Depends: fonts-arphic-bkai00mp but it is not installed
                    Depends: fonts-arphic-bsmi00lp but it is not installed
                    Depends: fonts-arphic-gbsn00lp but it is not installed
                    Depends: fonts-arphic-gkai00mp but it is not installed
   texlive-lang-korean : Depends: fonts-baekmuk but it is not installed
                   Depends: fonts-unfonts-extra but it is not installed
   texlive-lang-other : Depends: fonts-sil-padauk (>= 3.003-1) but 2.80-2 is installed
   texlive-plain-extra : Depends: texlive-plain-generic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installed
   texlive-pstricks : Depends: texlive-plain-generic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installed
   texlive-science : Depends: texlive-lang-greek (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

There are no held packages:

```
ralmond@Limu:~$ sudo apt-mark showhold
ralmond@Limu:~$
```

If I try a dist-upgrade again, I get very similar error messages:

```
ralmond@Limu:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     debhelper : Depends: dh-autoreconf (>= 17~) but it is not installed
         Depends: dh-strip-nondeterminism (>= 0.028~) but 0.015-1 is installed
     libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.1-2ubuntu1) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu1 is installed
... [Removing nearly identical list of broken packages.]
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

The -f option doesn't seem to help.

```
ralmond@Limu:~$ sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
      debhelper : Depends: dh-autoreconf (>= 17~) but it is not installed
         Depends: dh-strip-nondeterminism (>= 0.028~) but 0.015-1 is installed
...
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Removing a package has similar issues:

```
ralmond@Limu:~$ sudo apt-get -f remove debhelper
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  alien : Depends: debhelper (>= 7) but it is not going to be installed
  dh-strip-nondeterminism : Depends: debhelper but it is not going to be installed
  dh-translations : Depends: debhelper but it is not going to be installed
  libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.1-2ubuntu1) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
  libhtml-parser-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.26.0-4) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 is to be installed
                   Depends: perlapi-5.26.0
  libnet-ssleay-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.26.1-4build1) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 is to be installed
                  Depends: perlapi-5.26.1
  libxml-libxml-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.26.1-2ubuntu1) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 is to be installed
                  Depends: perlapi-5.26.1
  libxml-parser-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.26.0-4) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 is to be installed
                  Depends: perlapi-5.26.0
  systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 229-4ubuntu21.2) but 237-3ubuntu10 is to be installed
  texlive-binaries : Depends: libharfbuzz0b (>= 1.4.1) but 1.0.1-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
                Depends: libmpfr6 (>= 3.1.3) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libpoppler73 (>= 0.62.0) but it is not going to be installed
  texlive-extra-utils : Depends: libunicode-linebreak-perl but it is not going to be installed
  texlive-generic-extra : Depends: texlive-plain-generic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
  texlive-generic-recommended : Depends: texlive-plain-generic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
  texlive-lang-chinese : Depends: fonts-arphic-bkai00mp but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: fonts-arphic-bsmi00lp but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: fonts-arphic-gbsn00lp but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: fonts-arphic-gkai00mp but it is not going to be installed
  texlive-lang-korean : Depends: fonts-baekmuk but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: fonts-unfonts-extra but it is not going to be installed
  texlive-lang-other : Depends: fonts-sil-padauk (>= 3.003-1) but 2.80-2 is to be installed
  texlive-plain-extra : Depends: texlive-plain-generic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
  texlive-pstricks : Depends: texlive-plain-generic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
  texlive-science : Depends: texlive-lang-greek (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

It really looks like somehow debhelper is broken.  I'm afraid to get too aggressive about removing it for fear that I will break the entire debian system and not be able to move forwards or backwards.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions about what to try next.

**Update 1:**  Following this link ([Unmet dependencies error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612593/unmet-dependencies-error?rq=1)).  It suggested trying `dpkg --purge --pending`.  This did not solve my problem, but I think it provided a clue.  Here is the output:

```
ralmond@Limu:~$ sudo dpkg --purge --pending
[sudo] password for ralmond: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of texlive:
  mathtex depends on texlive.

dpkg: error processing package texlive (--purge):
  dependency problems - not removing
(Reading database ... 545797 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing systemd-shim (9-1bzr4ubuntu1) ...
Removing 'diversion of /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service to /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.systemd by systemd-shim'
  dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service' with
  different file '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.systemd', not allowed
dpkg: error processing package systemd-shim (--purge):
  installed systemd-shim package post-removal script subprocess 
returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
  texlive
  systemd-shim
```

Comment: Did you do a Debian style `dist-upgrade`? Or did you do an Ubuntu-style `do-release-upgrade`? They are different, the wrong one may break your Ubuntu system.

Comment: Here is the sequence of commands I used to do the upgrade:  156  sudo apt dist-update
  157  sudo apt dist-upgrade
  158  sudo apt update
  159  sud apt autoremove
  160  sudo apt autoremove
  161  sudo emacs -nw /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
  162  sudo do-release-upgrade -d

Comment: Seems like you used the wrong one. Back up your data. Then run `do-release-upgrade`. It might save your system, it might not. Ubuntu is *based* closely upon Debian, but there are important differences.

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me 'Searching for a new Ubuntu release.  No new release found.' so it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: You have two choices: Reinstall, or tediously sifting all those packages manually until you find the held package that's preventing the rest from upgrading. Your choice.

Comment: File a bug report against the package missing dependencies

Comment: the `do-release-upgrade` to 18.04 isn't visible to 16.04, until after 18.04.1 is released; so 'no release found' is still correct.  That path isn't expected to be opened until a few days after 26-July-2018.  The -d may get you to 18.04 now if you don't want to wait (but be careful you don't jump to 18.10)

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have PPAs added in `/etc/apt/sources.list/*.list` files? Did you try `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade`?

Comment: I checked everything in '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list' and they are all commented out.  I don't have 'aptitude' installed and 'apt-get install' also seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer.  It is slow and painful, but I hope it will get me there.  (I'm partway through).

1) First I removed as many packages as I could using `dpkg -r`(for example, all of the texlive packages are not system critical and I can reinstall them later, so I cleaned as many of those as I could.

2) For the packages that are actually part of the system, I used the following steps:

a) Use `sudo apt-get -f install` to check what is still broken.

```
ralmond@Limu:~/packageDepot$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.1-2ubuntu1) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libhtml-parser-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.26.0-4) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 is installed
                   Depends: perlapi-5.26.0
 libnet-ssleay-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.26.1-4build1) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 is installed
                  Depends: perlapi-5.26.1
 libxml-parser-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.26.0-4) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 is installed
                  Depends: perlapi-5.26.0
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 229-4ubuntu21.2) but 237-3ubuntu10 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

2) Working one package at a time, use `apt-get install` to check for missing dependencies.  Next on the list is glib2, so:

```
ralmond@Limu:~/packageDepot$ sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   libglib2.0-0 : Breaks: libglib2.0-0:i386 (!= 2.56.1-2ubuntu1) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
   libglib2.0-0:i386 : Breaks: libglib2.0-0 (!= 2.48.2-0ubuntu1) but 2.56.1-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
   libhtml-parser-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.26.0-4) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 is to be installed
   ... 
   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Ah!  There is a dependency on the i386 version.  Run again to check that the i386 version doesn't have any dependencies.

```
ralmond@Limu:~/packageDepot$ sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-0:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   libhtml-parser-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.26.0-4) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 is to be installed
   ... [Same list of packages]
   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Next, I manually download the files using `apt-get download`.  Note, don't run this as root or the files will not be deletable without `sudo`.

```
ralmond@Limu:~/packageDepot$ apt-get download libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0- 0:i386
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libglib2.0-0 amd64 2.56.1-2ubuntu1 [1,167 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 libglib2.0-0 i386 2.56.1-2ubuntu1 [1,232 kB]
Fetched 2,399 kB in 7s (323 kB/s)
```

Now manually install using `dpkg -i`.

```
ralmond@Limu:~/packageDepot$ sudo dpkg -i ./libglib*
(Reading database ... 421587 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-0_2.56.1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
 De-configuring libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.48.2-0ubuntu1) ...
 Unpacking libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.56.1-2ubuntu1) over (2.48.2-0ubuntu1) ...
 Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-0_2.56.1-2ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
 Unpacking libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.56.1-2ubuntu1) over (2.48.2-0ubuntu1) ...
 Setting up libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.56.1-2ubuntu1) ...
 Setting up libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.56.1-2ubuntu1) ...
 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

Now back to `apt-get -f install` to fix the next problem.

I'll update if I discover more steps are needed.

Comment: Eventually, drilling down in this way, I discovered that `ubuntu-release-updater-core` and `update-manager-core` were among the broken packages.  Fixing those seems to have fixed `apt-get -f install`.

Comment: Thanks for the write up.
After running the below many many times, I finally fixed all the broken packages.
"apt install -f"
"apt download ..."
"dpkg -i ..."